# System.out.println - cannot resolve symbol

Tags: java

I'm getting the following message:

```
 Cannot resolve method 'println(java.lang.String)'
```

In the following code and have absolutely no idea why that can be the case:

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.DataInputStream;

public class ChatServer {
    private final Socket theSocket;
    private final ServerSocket theServerSocket;
    private final DataInputStream theDataInputStream;

    public ChatServer(Socket aSocket, ServerSocket aServerSocket, DataInputStream aDataInputStream) {
          theSocket = aSocket;
          theServerSocket = aServerSocket;
          theDataInputStream = aDataInputStream;
     }

     public void start(int port) {
          System.out.println("Whatever");
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you have jdk libraries in your classpath??

Comment: Can you post the complete code along with the caller? Also what is java version and see if other java methods are working.

Comment: @instanceOfObject IMHO there is no need for more code as it seems clear that the environment seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any IDE or writing in a notepad and then compiling?
If using IDE, check if JRE library is there in build path. If using plain editor, you may need to setup CLASSPATH environment variable with java library.

At least `<java_home>\jre\lib\rt.jar` is important one.